# How to show only chapter name in each page only?

Tags: header-footer

Hello respected everyone.

I need little help from you. Please tell the (simpler) latex commands etc using which I can prepare every page lay out in documentclass "book" so that in each page there will be a horizontal line in above and only the chapter name will be seen.

I tried with "fancyheader" but I am not satisfied as it is showing the sections as well as chapter name both.

I want only the chapter name. What to do ?

Please help me

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\cfoot{\thepage \,of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyhead{}
\chead{\leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}



\setlength{\topmargin}{-.3in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{10.2in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.3in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{.2in}







\begin{document}
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 

text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 

text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 

text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 

text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 

text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 

text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 

text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 

text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 

text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 

text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 
text text text. text text text. text text text. text text text. 

\end{docuemnt}
```

Comment: @Harish Kumar Please suggest me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load package `fancyhdr` after setting the page margins. This is best down by package `geometry`. But to be honest, you should rethink your margins, they are too small. Or in other words, you text area is too big, which decreases readability.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{text={7in,10.2in}
,includehead
}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{-.3in}
%\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
%\setlength{\textheight}{10.2in}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.3in}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-.3in}
%\setlength{\topskip}{.2in}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\cfoot{\thepage \,of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyhead{}
\chead{\leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have used it sir. The following issuer are coming. (1) The header line is too small. I want it to be larger in length. How will I customize it? (2)I want the chapter name over the pages. but here nothing is coming. 

Kindly note that I have updated the file and have just posted. This is the exact page settings. Please use this and kindly help me. Thank you

Comment: ya ya it worked. Now only chapter name is coming. Thank GOD. But still problem is there. The header line is too small and the chapter name also not coming at the center position. What to do sir?

Comment: @AnjanDebnath Please see the update.